# How to fix "expected primary-expression before 'continue'"?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've started learning C++ and found myself in trouble with a simple problem. All that I need to do is to remove repeating spaces from stdin using a while loop, but I want to solve this problem with ternary if expressions.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool space = false;    // set to true if the symbol is ' '
                           // and reset to false if it's not
                           // if current symbol is ' ' 
                           // and bool is true (previous was also ' ') then
                           // I want to go to the next iteration
                           // without printing the current symbol which is repeating ' '
    char c = '\0';
    while (cin.get(c)) {
        c != ' ' ? space = false : !space ? space = true : continue;
        cout << c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile this code I get an error message:

```
expected primary-expression before 'continue'
```

How do I get out of this situation?

Upd: Using usual ifs is not the answer that I want because I'm not new to programming, I'm new to C++. I know how to solve this with ifs, just want to try other ways.

Comment: drop using the conditional operator and use a if..else statements.  It makes the code easier to read and will actually compile if you do so.

Comment: Don't abuse the conditional expression like that – its purpose is to choose between two *values*, and is not a shorthand for the conditional statement `if ... else ...`.

Comment: Being new to a language means accepting its idioms. Don't say you don't want regular `if`s

Comment: @Jeffrey I didn't say that I want to avoid `if`s for my entire life. I wanted to get used to `?:` operator so decided to try to solve this problem using that. This is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this obscure construction:

```
c != ' ' ? space = false : !space ? space = true : continue;
```

is meant to be this:

```
if(space && c == ' ') continue;
space = c == ' ';
```

That is, if the previous character was a space and the current is too, `continue`, otherwise, set `space` to `true` if the current is a space and `false` if it's not.

---

> I want to solve this problem with ternary if expressions.

```
e1 ? e2 : e3
```

The result of `e2` and `e3` must be convertible into the same value type (see [`expr.cond`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond)). `continue` is a statement (expression). It can't be convered to `bool` as it should have to be in this case - so, you need to split up your expressions and put the statement where it belongs.

You can however use a `throw` expression like this:

```cpp
    while (cin.get(c)) {
        try {
            c != ' ' ? space = false : !space ? space = true : throw 0;
            cout << c;
        } catch(...) {}
    }
```

... and this is exactly what exceptions should **not** be used for - but it "solves" your struggle with the conditional operator.